# React/Next.js recommended way to set constants such as backend API URLs

Tags: reactjs, configuration, next.js

I am looking through `next.js` documentation and trying to understand what the suggested approach is for setting URLs that change in different environments. Mostly, I want to ensure that I'm pointing backend URLs correctly in development versus production.

I suppose you can create a constants configuration file, but is there a supported, best practice for this?

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/environment-variables ?

Comment: Since Next.js 9.4, the recommended way to configure environment variables is documented in https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables.

Answer (score 2):

Open next.config.js and add publicRuntimeConfig config with your constants:

```
module.exports = {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
// Will be available on both server and client
yourKey: 'your-value'
},
}
```

you can call it from another .js file like this

```
import getConfig from 'next/config'
const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig()
console.log(publicRuntimeConfig.yourKey)
```

or even call it from view like this

```
${publicRuntimeConfig.yourKey}
```

Comment: This feature is [deprecated](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/runtime-configuration)

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your next app using [`next-runtime-dotenv`](https://github.com/tusbar/next-runtime-dotenv), it allows you to specify **serverOnly** / **clientOnly** values using next's runtime config.

Then in some component

```
import getConfig from 'next/config'

const {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {MY_API_URL},  // Available both client and server side
  serverRuntimeConfig: {GITHUB_TOKEN} // Only available server side
} = getConfig()

function HomePage() {
  // Will display the variable on the server’s console
  // Will display undefined into the browser’s console
  console.log(GITHUB_TOKEN)

  return (
    <div>
      My API URL is {MY_API_URL}
    </div>
  )
}

export default HomePage
```

If you don't need this separation, you can use `dotenv` lib to load your `.env` file, and configure Next's `env` property with it.

```
// next.config.js

require('dotenv').config()
module.exports = {
  env: {
    // Reference a variable that was defined in the .env file and make it available at Build Time
    TEST_VAR: process.env.TEST_VAR,
  },
}
```

Check this [with-dotenv](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-dotenv) example.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options depending on whether you'd like to check the constants in your version control system or not.

1. **Checking in via the [`next.config.js`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/env) (`env` property)**:

   You can add any key/value pair in this file like this:

   ```js
   module.exports = {
     env: {
       customKey: 'my-value',
     },
   }
   ```

   Now you can access `process.env.customKey` in your code. For example:

   ```js
   function Page() {
     return <h1>The value of customKey is: {process.env.customKey}</h1>
   }

   export default Page
   ```
2. **Keeping the constants in a separate [`.env.local`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables) file to differentiate your local and production environments**:

   You can add any key/value pair in this file like this:

   ```
   DB_HOST=localhost
   DB_USER=myuser
   DB_PASS=mypassword
   ```

   These variables will also be accessible via the environment variables. For example:

   ```js
   myDB.connect({
     host: process.env.DB_HOST,
     username: process.env.DB_USER,
     password: process.env.DB_PASS,
   })
   ```